# Disable stylelint warnings in certain cases

Tags: css, sass, frontend, stylelint, linter

I'm trying to use autoprefixer in a project. And I'm setting indentation to 2 spaces and max line lenght to 80 characters. The thing is that these two settings seem to conflict with one another in several cases. Let's say i have:

```
@mixin do-something($value, $otherValue, $anotherValue,
    $yetAnotherValue) {
  border-bottom: ...
```

The warning here says that it's expecting the second line to have 0 indentation spaces:

```
 2:5  ✖  Expected indentation of 0 spaces     indentation
```

Is there a way to make stylelint ignore these cases. Something like an *"Ignore indentation Indentation in line after class (or mixin) is declared"*?

Answer (score 1):

Just give a look at this https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration/#turning-rules-off-from-within-your-css it may be your case.

Comment: It was not exactly what I needed but I found some useful stuff here. Thank you! (I need something that I can apply globally instead of turning off the tool each time I need an exception)

Comment: But I need it turned off only in certain places and for certain properties. Not all. I want to generate an exception in certain cases. I know that can be done, but I'm not sure how to declare the exceptions I need.